# Is there a way I can modify the opacity of cmd with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I'm currently using Python to design a console app and thought it would look nice to use a different cmd opacity.

I was looking into cmd commands to see if there was something similar to `color` so that I could do `os.system(command)`, but I wasn't able to find anything.

Are there any ways? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean changing the font color? I don't think there is a way, except not using cmd and using a pygame/PyQt window

Comment: Microsoft documented all [Console Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) of the Windows kernel library kernel32.dll. It is possible to use those console functions of Windows directly in a Python script, or use a Python module which is a Python wrapper for the Windows console functions. There is no function to control the opacity of a console window. The opacity is always 100% which of course is highly recommended for a pure text window to be readable for users.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know if there are any specific libraries that can accomplish console control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to find a library that handled cmd functions, I tried the next best thing I could think of. It's not a clean solution and I hope to mark the next best answer as a solution in the future, but for now I was able to use this:

```py
import pyautogui

# 90% Transparency
for _ in range(1):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", "-")

# 80% Transparency
for _ in range(2):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", "-")

# 70% Transparency
for _ in range(3):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", "-")

# 60% Transparency
for _ in range(4):
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", "-")

# and so on
```

This may not work if the user also switches out of the application immediately, but I have not tested that yet.